# Prove this polynomial has no integer solution

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$$144x^5 − 121x^4 + 100x^3 − 81x^2 − 64x + 49 = 0 $$

I re-wrote it as

$$ 12^2x^5 - 11^2x^4 + 10^2x^3 - 9^2x^2 - 8^2x + 7^2 = 0 $$

And then as $$ \sum_{k=0}^{5} (k+7)^2(-1)^kr^k = 0 $$

But I don't know what to do with that. Thanks for any help!

Comment: if $n\in \mathbb Z$ were a root, then $n\,|\,49$.

Comment: If $\frac{m}{n}$ is a rational irreducible root of a polynomial $a_nX^n + ... \ + \ a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $m | a_0$, and $n | a_n$.

Comment: the $(-1)^k$  in your sum is incorrect: the $x$ and $x^2$ terms are both negative!

Answer (score 7):

Generally, the best way to do these kinds of problems is by the rational root theorem. However, there is a nicer way here.

Consider this polynomial $\mod 2$. If it has a solution $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then

$$-121n^4-81n^2+49\equiv 0\mod 2$$

$$n^4+n^2+1\equiv 0\mod 2$$

$$(n^2)(n^2+1)+1\equiv 0\mod 2$$

However, $n^2$ and $n^2+1$ are of opposite parity, so their product is even and the LHS is $\equiv 1\mod 2$. This is a contradiction, and thus there are no integer roots to the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Assume. n is an integer solution.

Then (x-n) would be a factor of the polynomial.

Then n would have to be a divisor of 49.

The only possibilities for n are positive or negative  1,  7,  &  49.

Substitution of these 6 possibilities shows that none are solutions.

Therefore no integer solutions exist.